# how to get facebook account details i, asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

how to get facebook account details in asp.net??
is that possible to get account details from facebook to my website
i want to access username , email, picture , location, birthdate

```
 if (provider != "facebook")
    {
        //do normal oauth
    }
    else
    {
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();

        var loginUrl = client.GetLoginUrl(new
        {
            client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookId"],
            client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookClientSecret"],
            redirect_uri = redirectUrl,
            response_type = "code",
            scope = "email,user_birthday"
        });

        Response.Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

i tried that but face a lot of problem EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986 not found 
like what provider  definition 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookId"]?
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookClientSecret"]??

Answer (score 0):

there are a set of stuffs you need to do to connect to FB

- you need to register to FB  by creating a API @ developers.facebook.com/‎
- Generate the Access token and secret key for your api
- Download the FB-js Sdk and refer in your page/site
- use the key`s above generated to connect to Facebook

one best tutorial for .net  application connecting to FB is http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/

which explains every section clearly.

Comment: dynamic me = client.Get("totten");  how can change totten to current FB account ??

Comment: @user3195022: `Nathan Totten` is a public account, which does not require you to login to Facebook. if you thinking to access any users account details who is currenlty logged to your site , then i would suggest you to go for FB-JS sdk, which you need to download and refer in your site.for secure authentication to FB, you need to register your app at FB developers site use the `secret key ` & `Access Token`.i guess you need to refer to the tutorial u will understand better